# Indexing Array Items In Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that looks something like ...

```js
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    sizes: [{
        type: String,
        enum: [/* some fixed sizes */],
    }],
    // other properties ...
});
```

I perform queries of the form `Items.find({ sizes: { $elemMatch: 'someSize' } });`
So I want to add index to those sizes inside of an element so the query is performed quickly.

Should it be something like:

```js
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    sizes: [{
        type: String,
        enum: [/* some fixed sizes */],
        index: true,
    }],
    // other properties ...
});
```

or

```js
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    sizes: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: [/* some fixed sizes */],
        }],
        index: true,
    },
    // other properties ...
});
```

or maybe a third option ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I discovered that what I wanted is called **Multikey Indexing** and found its docs on [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey).

According to that, indexing a field whose type is an array will create an index for each field of the array all pointing to the same document, which is exactly what I wanted to optimize my queries.

So the right answer would be

```js
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    sizes: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: [/* some fixed sizes */],
        }],
        index: true,
    },
    // other properties ...
});
```

but on experimenting and checking collection indexes (with compass), I found that this

```js
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    sizes: [{
        type: String,
        enum: [/* some fixed sizes */],
        index: true,
    }],
    // other properties ...
});
```

will also work in the same manner and will create an index on `sizes` field which will be a multikey index.

So pretty much the 2 forms are acceptable, and are working as expected; I prefer the one that explicitly indexes the `sizes` field though.

Answer (score 2):

You can define [indexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) as part of the type declaration like this:

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    sizes: [{
        type: String,
        enum: ['foo', 'bar'],
        index: true,
    }],
    // other properties ...
});
```

You could also define them as @Eduardo mention after the fact via something like this:

```
itemSchema.index({ _id: 1 }, { sparse: true });
```

All is in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes).

Comment: I thought about this, but was not sure it would work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What i do for indexing is:
Below the schema i'll write `itemSchema.index({'sizes':1});`
You can check here in mongoose documentation for more info 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

Comment: This is not quite what I want, I wanted to index the inner objects of the array, not the array itself

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @Amr Saber & @Akrion 's answer, 
If anyone want also **define default or required** values,

```
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    sizes: [{ 
      type: [{
         type: String,
         enum: [/* some fixed sizes */],
         index: true,
      }],
      required: true, 
      default: [] 
    }],
    // other properties ...
});
```

can be used. It seems to work fine for me.